# Drupal Google Tag Manager breaks HTML

Tags: php, regex, drupal

GTM module author inserts GTM code by using regex and dynamically change page source. As a result of wrong regex, in my specific case it breaks HTML. Can't understand why didn't he use any hooks for that.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <body id="homepage" class="ie ie6 html front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-second page-node page-node- page-node-603 node-type-panel tao">
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
...............
<!-- End Google Tag Manager --> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <body id="homepage" class="ie ie7 html front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-second page-node page-node- page-node-603 node-type-panel tao"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <body id="homepage" class="ie ie8 html front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-second page-node page-node- page-node-603 node-type-panel tao"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <body id="homepage" class="ie ie9 html front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-second page-node page-node- page-node-603 node-type-panel tao"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <body id="homepage" class="html front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-second page-node page-node- page-node-603 node-type-panel tao"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Plugin code (they just replace HTML using regex)

```
$children = preg_replace('@<body[^>]*>@', '$0' . $script, $children, 1);
```

How to fix that regex? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to match?

Comment: It breaks how, explain ...

Comment: everything is in an example. The first conditional comment + GA code will make so section will be added before body opening tag and after head closing tag.